# How to set PATH for all applications on a per-user basis?

Tags: macos, launchd, login, path, environment-variables

I'm looking for a way to set the `PATH` environment variable for **all** applications that **I** (and only I) run under macOS (version 14 / Sonoma at the time of writing.)  That sounds like it *ought* to be straightforward, but it seems not to be, and I haven't found any current, working instructions on how to do it.

To be clear, here are three things that I **do** know how to do, that there are (some) decent instructions out there for, and that are **not** what I'm asking about now:

1. Set the environment variables for a shell (e.g. zsh, bash, etc) and by extension applications that are launched *from* that shell.  All the normal UNIX techniques and configuration files work fine for this.  If I set a variable in my `~/.zshrc` and then start any app I want (GUI or not) from within zsh, it works as expected.
2. Set an environment variable which is **not** `PATH` for apps *not* launched from a shell.  There are several ways of doing that using `launchctl setenv`, and they're dirty and hackish, but they work.  I've written up one way of doing that at [Add system-wide environment-variables in MacOS Ventura](https://www.reddit.com/r/MacOS/comments/12ryky5/comment/k3qcjf3/?utm_source=reddit&utm_medium=web2x&context=3).  However, macOS appears to have special-case handling for `PATH` that's different from other environment variables.
3. Change the `PATH` variable for **all** users:  I can add entries to `/etc/paths` or `/etc/paths.d/` but then those affect everybody, which is actively unhelpful on a multi-user system, especially since I want to include some directories that other users can't even access.

So, those out of the way, does anyone know of a command, configuration file, settings option, magic incantation, etc. that will let me set the `PATH` variable given to any process I launch, no matter how I launch it (e.g as a login item, from Finder, from the dock, whatever) that doesn't involve making a system-wide change and messing up other users?

Comment: The location of the executable for most (if not all) applications is not found in the default PATH variable shown in a Terminal application window. In other words, I do not think macOS uses a PATH variable to find the applications.

Comment: So you're looking to set in stone a $PATH during a "pre-user-login" time window (if something like this exists), so that all of a user's apps (login apps and all apps everywhere) are guaranteed to inherit this $PATH after user login. Right now you have a solution (in the Reddit post) that sets $PATH during the "login" time window, where it's a race condition with other login apps, but you want these login apps to be guaranteed to inherit this $PATH. Can also try asking Unix SE if there's such a thing as a macOS per-user `/etc/paths`.

Comment: @Aeronautix, basically.  But even more than the race condition issue, there seems to be special-case handling of PATH (probably meant as a security precaution) that makes the approach I describe there work for _other_ environment variables, but _not_ PATH.

Comment: @DavidAnderson, yeah, it's not that macOS uses PATH to _find_ those apps, but rather that _they_ implicitly use PATH to find and launch other tools.  Concretely, there are utilities installed within my home directory that several different GUI programs might invoke to format or check code, but if I start those programs from Finder with the default PATH, they're not found.  I can _probably_ configure each application to do the right thing individually, but not all applications are configurable, and not having to do that is what environment variables are _for_.

Comment: Try putting `export PATH=<your_path_here>${PATH:+:$PATH}` in the user's `~/.zshenv`, does that work? This startup file is always sourced and is near the top of the invocation hierarchy for `zsh` startup files, and it seems to work alright for me, testing with an Automator login application.

Comment: @Aeronautix, thanks for the suggestion, but I think that's the same as my non-solution #1:  It works *if* we're starting applications from the shell, but not if they're launched straight from finder/launchd, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: Unless there's any objection, I'm going to try relocating this to a different Stack Exchange site to see if anybody has an answer there.  Many thanks for all the input here!